# Error while am try to update it

Tags: installation, grub2, updates, update-manager, error-handling

W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run these commands in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And also check your internet connection.